# How to load a dataset from filenames in tensorflow, with input png and npy files

Tags: tensorflow

I have to load 2 images and 1 array from filenames with this format:

> /nuove/corridoio_22092021/left/220921_141.png
> /nuove/corridoio_22092021/right/220921_141.png
> /nuove/corridoio_22092021/M/220921_141.npy

They are separated by a space..
I want to split each file path and load the images with `tf.decode_png`
but **how to load the npy file in tensorflow?**

Maybe I can use

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset([filenames_file])
```

but how should I proceed?

Comment: `*.npy` files are usually NumPy binary files. Check out  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.io.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.load` to load the array and then use the array as required.